# R dplyr method mutate variable if exists

Tags: r, dplyr

As a big fan of dplyr and its tidy data concept, I would like to mutate a specific variable whenever it exists in a dataframe. This is the idea:

```
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)

# Create data frames
df1 <- data.frame(year = 2000:2010, foo = 0:10)
df2 <- data.frame(year = 2000:2010)

# Create function
cnd_mtt <- function(df){
  df %>%
    mutate_if(colname == "foo", as.factor) # <---- this is the tricky part
}
```

Expected result: the function should work for both data frames and without error

Ideas?

Comment: what's `colname`?

Comment: How about an `if` statement: `if("foo" in names(df)) ...`

Comment: @Gregor must be `%in%`, see my answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `mutate_at` with `one_of` which raises a warning message if the column doesn't exist:

```
cnd_mtt <- function(df){
    df %>%
        mutate_at(vars(one_of('foo')), as.factor)
}

cnd_mtt(df2)
#   year
#1  2000
#2  2001
#3  2002
#4  2003
#5  2004
#6  2005
#7  2006
#8  2007
#9  2008
#10 2009
#11 2010
```

> ```
> Warning message:
> Unknown variables: `foo`
> ```

Just to clarify, the warning message is raised by `one_of` when it fails to resolve the column name from the `vars` variable:

```
one_of('foo', vars = names(df1))
# [1] 2
one_of('foo', vars = names(df2))
# integer(0)
```

> ```
> Warning message:
> Unknown variables: `foo`
> ```

---

In case you want to further get rid of the warning message, take @Gregor's comment, you can use `mutate_at` with `if/else`, and returns `integer(0)` if `foo` doesn't exist in the columns:

```
df2 %>% 
    mutate_at(if('foo' %in% names(.)) 'foo' else integer(0), as.factor)

#   year
#1  2000
#2  2001
#3  2002
#4  2003
#5  2004
#6  2005
#7  2006
#8  2007
#9  2008
#10 2009
#11 2010
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works well!

Answer (score 1):

Building on Psidom answer, you can also use `quietly` to avoid the warning:

```
df2 %>%
  mutate_at(vars(quietly(one_of)("foo","boo",  .vars = tidyselect::peek_vars())$result),
            as.factor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a basic pipe operation, untethered to dplyr I believe. Also try not to use df as variable name

```
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)

# Create data frames
df1 <- data.frame(year = 2000:2010, foo = 0:10)
df2 <- data.frame(year = 2000:2010)

# Create function
cnd_mtt <- function(dff,colname){
    if (colname %in% names(dff)){
        dff%>%mutate(new_col=some.transformation)
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work well along many other pipes (%>%) in the function (tidy data concept). Psidoms answer is good for me.